# pytest: Grouping tests by expensive operation

Tags: python, pytest

TL;DR: `pytest`: how to group tests such that they only run for certain configurations but not others (sort of the opposite of parametrization, which triggers cross-product execution of tests across all permutations).

I'm fairly new to `pytest`, hopefully there's a way to do this and I'm just not seeing it. Would appreciate your input. I've been poking around for a while and haven't (yet) found something that addresses this specific situation; I will keep looking.

Our team has an existing (read: inherited) suite of tests (900+ .py files; quality is medium to low, tests aren't repeatable and don't clean up well after themselves, at least not consistently) that we are wanting to clean up and convert to `pytest` (please suggest other frameworks if you feel they might be better suited to our situation). Generally the test execution flow is something like this:

```
1. Create unit-under-test object (very expensive)
2. Apply default config          (also expensive; optional; each .py file opts-in/out)
3. Execute test function         (may tweak config, doesn't always clean up)
4. Tear down 2                   (partial cleanup, doesn't fully restore baseline state)
5. Repeat 2-4 for all test fns   (remember 2 is expensive!)
```

Notes:

- created object cannot be cached or saved/retrieved
- object creation (step 1) involves the use of *properties* (a collection of name/value pairs). Some are environmental (command line, env var, etc.) and apply to all tests. Others are specified in the .py file at object creation time.  So there will of course be a finite number of property *profiles* (unique permutations of properties and their values) across the .py files
- currently each .py file must be executed separately
- steps 1 and 2 account for over 95% of the elapsed time for running all tests
- an additional 4% or more is consumed by loading python modules (very large SWIG-generated APIs to interact with C++ code, the actual thing being tested here), a *tax* which gets paid for every .py file currently (recall they run separately)
- so actual test execution represents less than 1% of the total time

Needless to say, the primary goal here is to eliminate most of this overhead by grouping tests across files that use the same property profile (object creation, step 1) and default config opt-in/out (step 2).

Most of the test transformation will be (I think) straightforward (e.g. using the `setup -> yield -> cleanup` pattern in fixtures, etc.).

The challenge is to find a way to group tests such that they *only* get executed for the specific `<property profile, default-config opt-in/out>` permutation that is applicable to them (remembering that the property profiles are dynamically determined at run time), but only perform the expensive operations once per group. Parametrization appears to do the opposite of this, since it enables a cross-product execution of tests for *all* permutations. Further, the [pytest-dependency](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-dependency/) plugin doesn't appear to offer anything that might help (at least not on the surface). And I haven't figured out a way to use `skipif()` such that it avoids performing the expensive operations before evaluating the condition (besides, how would one even write the condition given the nature of the operands in this scenario?).

Would this require us writing our own plugin? My first few attempts at delving into this have not been very successful, though I'll keep at it.

I would appreciate your insights.

Thanks for your attention (sorry this is a bit long).

Comment: Could you use markers for tests for different parameter sets, and run only tests for a specific marker in each test run?

Comment: @MrBean-Bremen, thanks for the suggestion. Parameter sets would typically not be known ahead of time, rather by each test specifying the parameters they need. Could the tests be marked as part of (or right after) collection?  If so then this might work: (1) collect the parameter sets, (2) insert a per-parameter-set marker to each test (class), then (3) perform N execution passes, one for each marker.  Is this what you're suggesting? Does pytest allow such capabilities?

Comment: You can implement `pytest_collection_modifyitems` and add markers to the items (`item.add_marker`) at that point, if you have the needed information, though the third part is a bit difficult - you may have to implement `pytest_runtestloop` to execute several test runs.

Comment: It would help if you had some minimal reproducible example (with a couple of scenarios and tests) to better understand the problem.

Comment: @MrBean-Bremen, thanks for the follow-up, I will definitely take a look at that and circle back.  I'll also try to contrive an example I can paste here (the above was getting a bit long already).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found *a* solution that seems to be working, so I thought I'd share here. I wouldn't call it elegant by any stretch, but I can probably make progress with it.

Using a decorator to specify the properties and the default-config setting for a given test class, the information can be gathered into a mapping of class to profile.  Then an alternate implementation of `pytest_runtestloop` allows the grouping of tests by profile.

I would much rather have used fixtures in some way or other, but with most attempts I ended up deep-diving into pytest internals, needing to import `_pytest` and writing many times the amount of code.

Here's the implementation I came up with:

test.py:

```py
from conftest import object_setup

@object_setup(
    properties = dict(PROP1=1, PROP2=2, PROP3=3),
    uses_default_config = True
)
class Test1:

    def test_1(self, the_object):
        print(f'-- T1: {the_object}')

@object_setup(
    properties = dict(PROP1=1, PROP2=2, PROP3=3),
    uses_default_config = True
)
class Test2:

    def test_2(self, the_object):
        print(f'-- T2: {the_object}')

@object_setup(uses_default_config = False)
class Test3:

    def test_3(self, the_object):
        print(f'-- T3: {the_object}')

def test_other():
    print(f'-- OTHER')
```

conftest.py:

```py
import collections
import pytest

Profile = collections.namedtuple('Profile', 'properties uses_default_config')

# global variable -- ugh
the_obj = None

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def the_object(request):
    print(f'-> OBJ {the_obj}')
    yield the_obj
    print(f'<- OBJ {the_obj}')

class object_setup(object):
    by_class = {}

    def __init__(self, properties={}, uses_default_config=False):
        self.profile = Profile(
            properties=frozenset(tuple(prop) for prop in properties.items()),
            uses_default_config=uses_default_config
        )

    def __call__(self, cls):
        self.__class__.by_class[cls] = self.profile
        class Wrapped(cls):
            __obj_orig_cls__ = cls
            pass
        return Wrapped

def pytest_runtestloop(session):
    if session.testsfailed and not session.config.option.continue_on_collection_errors:
        raise session.Interrupted(
            "%d error%s during collection"
            % (session.testsfailed, "s" if session.testsfailed != 1 else "")
        )

    if session.config.option.collectonly:
        return True

    global the_obj
    by_class = object_setup.by_class
    grouped = { None: [] }

    for item in session.items:
        profile = None
        cls = getattr(item.cls, '__obj_orig_cls__', None)
        profile = by_class.get(cls, None)
        grouped.setdefault(profile, []).append(item)

    for profile, items in grouped.items():
        the_obj = { 'the': 'object', 'profile': profile }

        try:
            for i, item in enumerate(items):
                nextitem = items[i + 1] if i + 1 < len(items) else None
                item.config.hook.pytest_runtest_protocol(item=item, nextitem=nextitem)
                if session.shouldfail:
                    raise session.Failed(session.shouldfail)
                if session.shouldstop:
                    raise session.Interrupted(session.shouldstop)
        finally:
            the_obj = None

    return True
```

And the output:

```
pytest --setup-show test.py
============================== test session starts ===============================
============================== test session starts ===============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.2, pytest-6.2.3, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/userid/Documents/test_pytest/try
collected 4 items

test.py
        test.py::test_other.
SETUP    S the_object
        test.py::Test1::test_1 (fixtures used: request, the_object).
        test.py::Test2::test_2 (fixtures used: request, the_object).
TEARDOWN S the_object
SETUP    S the_object
        test.py::Test3::test_3 (fixtures used: request, the_object).
TEARDOWN S the_object

=============================== 4 passed in 0.01s ================================
```

More detailed output shows that the correct profile is used in each case, and that object creation/destruction occurs at the right points.